# How to listen to different channels of logs of NodeJS running NestJS in a Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs

I have a NestJS application running in a Docker container. I have two loggers; the NestJS Logger and Pino.

Pino is responsible for listening to requests and responses and printing them to the console, while I use the NestJS logger to print custom messages I output, and for logging errors and the such.

I essentially want to open two terminal windows for each one of the loggers and only get logs by one of the two on each. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure to save each log in the two different files during execution, for example: req-res-log.txt and custom-log.txt, after open the terminal window and use the command "tail -f -n100 file-path" to show logs during your test.